Android Studio Menu Issues
I'm not a developer but I do manage several apps for clients and I came across an issue that my developer doesn't know how to fix...
When I open Android Studio my default menu isn't loading and instead I get the "Project" menu, I've encountered this once before but the developer of that time fixed it.
I am aware that if I click on the drop down menu I can just scroll down and select "Android" to get my default menu but in this case the option isn't there.

Im getting this menu instead.

And I'm pretty sure its related but I'm also not getting my run on device option on the top right corner.

Is this an easy fix? Is it related to how the code was edited last time? Or is it more of an Android Studio fix where I just need to activate these options.
Because the old code loads with the default menu and options to run on device, its just the new edited code thats giving me this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Try updating android studio from the Help menu. It often reconfigures and fixes things like this. Also try importing as an android project when you import it. File -> New -> Import Project

Updated my AS from eel to koala and also imported project, when importing and AS was indexing project it did load for a few seconds the "Android" option on the drop down menu but as soon as it finished importing it went back to the "Project" menu.
